# How to sync to custom taxonomies (tag structure)

Tags: taxonomy, tags, terms

I have two taxonomies: "Contributers" and "Narrators."

I want to sync the terms in these two taxonomies identically, so much so that I wish to be able to click on "Edit Term" and see the information (Description, Title, slug, etc.) duplicated in the partnering taxonomy.

Right now, I have this (below) which does indeed insert the term with identical slug and even identical term_id (instead of appending the slug with a number), however the Description does not sync (as they are different term_taxonomy_id's. All thoughts and suggestions are welcomed!

```
/**
 * Syncs the Contribute/Narrator Terms
 *
 * @param int $term_id
 * @param int $tt_id
 * @param string $taxonomy
 * @return string
 */
function lp_duplicate_created_terms( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( $taxonomy != 'contributer' && $taxonomy != 'narrator' )
        return;

    static $count = 0;

    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy );

    $opposite = ( $taxonomy == 'contributer' ) ? 'narrator' : 'contributer';

    // Prevents function from running a second time in the following wp_insert_term
    if ( $count > 0 )
        $count = 0;
    else
        wp_insert_term( $term->name, $opposite, array( 'slug' => $term->slug, 'alias_of' => $term->slug, 'description' => $term->description ) );
    $count++;
}
add_action( "created_term", 'lp_duplicate_created_terms', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Sorry, why? What is the point of having two different but mirror image taxonomies (which is what it seems like you are doing)?

Comment: I want the ability to add a "Contributer" to a post that might have been a "Narrator" in another post (thus auto-populating the taxonomy suggestions).

Also, I want to the taxonomy-post relationships to be independent of one another. If I add John Smith as a Narrator, I don't also want him to be a Contributer. I just want the data attached to the term "John Smith" to be the same as another post with the contributer, "John Smith.

Comment: Thank you for the great code! I already have a custom taxonomy containing a lot of terms. Now I need a second one with the same terms. Do you know if it’s possible to sync them e.g. when updating the existing ones? Thank you!